# what structured data objects should I use to manipulate data from a .txt?

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-structures

I have a little problem, I need to read a .txt file that store the result of a SQL query.

the file .txt file has the following structure

```
GMM-1473879866   |  212349876543 |   -150 | 14-SEP-16 03.04.26.000000 PM   | DebitBalance-[-150] |  212343214567 |     100 | 14-SEP-16 03.04.27.000000 PM   | Balance[150]
```

I mostly use PHP to process query results but right now I have to use java, is there any object, class, framework or library that could help me to store the data into an array, structure or so?

I want the data structure to look like this:

```
1 | GMM-1473879866   |  212349876543 |   -350 | 14-SEP-16 03.04.26.000000 PM   | Balance-[-150] |  212343214567 |     100 | 14-SEP-16 03.04.27.000000 PM   | Balance[150]
2 | GMM-1812568432   |  212345634411 |   -150 | 14-SEP-16 03.25.14.000000 PM   | Balance-[-150] |  212349081123 |     0 | 14-SEP-16 03.25.15.000000 PM   | Balance[150]
```

being 1..2...n some kind of array "key".

this data structure (ie. bidimensional array)  will be used to send some parameter to an API, the API need to be executed manually for every query row (usually 20/day) so this little software aim to automatize this process.

I can not modify or view the query code, so I need to work with this file, the program will be running automatically everyday.

Comment: You can use the same structures you would with PHP, from the very raw array/list of array of objects to a more refined collection of DTO, passing through an array/list of maps. The precise choice depends on the context.

Comment: You can treat the file as a CSV, but with pipes instead of commas. You can create your own class in Java with properties for each column (ie whatever the headers would be) and just parse the file line by line.

Comment: thanks boys i'll be expermenting to work around with those tips, didnt even notice that i could treat the file as a CSV or that i could actually manage the data as i was in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string split to parse each of the lines. Each line contains 9 groups separated by a pipe character which is surrounded by a variable amount of white-space. So your split regex looks like `"\s*|\s*"`. You then have to escape some characters to work in java... so you get `"\\s*\\|\\s*"`

```
final List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
try (final BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sqlqueuery.txt")))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        rows.add(line.split("\\s*\\|\\s*"));
    }

} catch (final IOException e) {
    //TODO handle errors
}
```

In terms of what data structure to use, you could just create a custom class with named fields for each on the individual cells.

Comment: really usefull, very thanks you!! i'll work around this!.